# Add Opacity to CGPath

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, cgpath

CGPathRef defines an opaque type that represents an immutable graphics path. CGMutablePathRef defines an opaque type that represents a mutable graphics path.

But how do we change the opacity in the `CGPath` in `CoreGraphics`? 
Can it be addd in percentage?

Comment: As Maarten says, you just make sure to set the `alpha` component of your stroke/fill colors, and you'll achieve the reduced opacity that you're looking for.

Comment: A path does not have color, opacity, or other such properties as intrinsic parts of itself. Those things are part of the graphics state, which is part of the context, and you set them when you go to draw the path. (And yes, this is different from most vector-graphics apps, where paths do have their own fill and/or stroke colors.)

Answer (score 2):

It's called "alpha" in UIKit and Core Graphics. For example:

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0.5f alpha:0.5f];
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, color.CGColor); // Assuming you have a context.
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Note that, under ARC, that code may crash because nothing owns the CGColor object past the first line. http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks for fixing such an embarrassing mistake.

Comment: @Maarten... thank you for that... what if I am doing this on a in CATransaction loop where there is no Context as such